# How do I resolve this javascript 404 error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, precompile

Im running into what seems like an odd issue. We made a slight change to our coffee javascript and then ran the clobber and precompile. Now for some reason the script works for about 30 seconds then it stops working for about 30 seconds. When its not working the browser console shows a 404 error when trying to include the script, and then obviously doesn't show that error when its working.

The page has an anchor tag that's supposed to open a modal window, the opening of the modal is what is either working/failing on and off. The coffee script change that we made was to the javascript that submits the form within the modal so it shouldn't be related.

Has anyone ever encountered something similar?

Edit: Just to add to this, this is happening for all users not just myself.

Comment: I think this is a problem specific to your code and build pipeline, and we cannot help. A 404 error is a network or server problem, not code. Maybe you should look at the CDN / server where you host your scripts. Or the build pipeline that uploads to it.

Comment: @caffeinated.tech - thanks for the response. It looks to have resolved itself on its own.